# Hover callback problem - doesn't display dataframe

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am new to Python and have limited coding experience, so any input and advice is deeply appreciated.

I have created a dynamic choropleth map which includes a scatter_geo plot that overlays the relevant areas.

I am trying create a hover callback so that when I hover over one of these points, a dataframe appears that is indexed according to the point id (the first column in the defined dataframe). Essentially, it is a choropleth map equivalent of this example: https://plotly.com/python/v3/cars-exploration/ but without using FigureWidget.

I keep getting stuck on the hover callback function; no dataframe displays when I hover. Below is the code I have so far.

```
license_df1 = pd.read_excel(lic, "Primary Holdings by License", dtype = "str").fillna('')
license_df2 = pd.read_excel(lic, "Secondary Holdings by License", dtype = "str").fillna('')


### CREATE PLOTTING FEATURES ###
app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions = True)
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P("Spectrum Band:"), # Create Toggle Items between spectrum bands
    dcc.RadioItems(id = "Band", options=[{'value': x, 'label':x} for x in df1_band], value = df1_band[0]),
    dcc.Graph(id = "choropleth"),
    dash_table.DataTable(id = "table")])

@app.callback(
    Output("choropleth", "figure"),
    [Input("Band", "value")])

def build_graph(value):
    
    if value == '600 MHz':
        df1_600 = df1[(df1["Band"] == "600 MHz")]
        fig1 = px.choropleth(df1_600, geojson = PEAs, featureidkey = "properties.PEA_Num",
                             locations = 'PEA # ', hover_data = {'PEA # ': False}, scope = "usa")


        # Overlay Geographic Scatter Plot for interactive functionality
        fig1b = px.scatter_geo(df1_600, geojson = PEAs, featureidkey = "properties.PEA_Num",
                                               locations = 'PEA # ', hover_name = 'Market', scope = "usa")

        fig1.add_trace(fig1b.data[0])                                           
        fig1.update_traces(showlegend = False)
        fig1.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

        return fig1

    elif value == '3.7 GHz':
        df1_3700 = df1[(df1["Band"] == "3.7 GHz")]

        fig2 = px.choropleth(df1_3700, geojson = PEAs, featureidkey = "properties.PEA_Num",
                             locations = 'PEA # ', hover_data = {'PEA # ': False}, scope = "usa")


        # Overlay Geographic Scatter Plot for interactive functionality
        fig2b = px.scatter_geo(df1_3700, geojson = PEAs, featureidkey = "properties.PEA_Num",
                               locations = 'PEA # ', hover_name = 'Market', scope = "usa")


        fig2.add_trace(fig2b.data[0])
        fig2.update_traces(showlegend = False)
        fig2.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

        return fig2
        

@app.callback(
    Output("table", "data"),
    [Input("fig1", "hover_data")]) # WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE 

def disp_license1(hover_data):
    table_vals = license_df1.iloc[points.point_inds[0]].to_frame().to_html()

    return table_vals


app.run_server(debug = True)
```